# Cache Vs Persist in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

1. In spark we have `cache` and `persist`, used to save the RDD.
2. As per my understanding `cache` and `persist/MEMORY_AND_DISK` both perform same action for DataFrames.
3. If this is the case why should I prefer using `cache` at all, I can always use `persist` [with different parameters] and ignore `cache`.
4. Could you please let me know, when to use `cache`, or if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no profound difference between `cache` and `persist`. Calling `cache()` is strictly equivalent to calling `persist` without argument which defaults to the `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level.

Here is the source code of the `cache()` method:

```scala
  /**
   * Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def cache(): this.type = persist()
```